# How to mock persisting data in repository until tests finished with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mockito, h2

To implement our tests, I need to retrieve saved data from a repository. Since the repository is just a Mocked repository I can't find these data.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;

public void functionTest(){
  User user = new User();
  user.setUsername("username");
  userRepository.save(user);
  List<User> users = functionIwantToTest();
  assertThat(users.size(), is(1));
}

public void functionIwantToTest(){
  return userRepository.findAll();
}
```

The test fail as the function will not find any user in the repository (the save function does not persist data in the repository)

This is a simple example, what I really want is to test a function that will retrieve specific users from the UserRepository, so I need to mock some data there.

I use PostgreSQL as runtime database. Is there any possibility to automatically use in-memory db (like h2 database) when I am running my tests? So I can save and retrieve data from the database without need to @Mock annotation?

Comment: use in memory database like `H2` show the config code

Comment: @Deadpool How it is possible to use in memory database automatically during tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use H2 during testing. Start by adding a dependency on H2 in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

To enable H2 in tests you can add `<your-project>/src/test/resources/application.properties` (or `application.yaml`)

```
h2.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:somedatebase;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
h2.datasource.username=sa
h2.datasource.password=
```

Then you need to `@Autowired` your `UserRepository`. After doing that I can run your example test successfully

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void functionTest(){
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("username");
        userRepository.save(user);
        List<User> users = functionIwantToTest();
        assertThat(users.size(), is(1));
    }

    public List<User> functionIwantToTest(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I will change my application.yam configuration file, and replace the PostgreSQL datasource with H2 database. I will no longer use the PostgreSQL during runtime? Is it possible to configure two datasrouces H2 for testing and Postgres for run time and make Spring pick the one I want based on the situation?

Comment: The `application.yaml` in `<your-project>/src/test/resources` will not be included in production if that is what you mean by runtime

Comment: @stodi Just to be clear. If you put the H2 configuration in the `application.yaml` in the `/test/` scope of your project it will not override what you already have when running in production

Comment: I didn't know that I can configure "another" `application.yml` file in the `/test/` folder. I was changing the configuration in the `/main/`. Now, I am updating the values in the application.yml in the `/test/` folder but I got `IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` exception.

Comment: @stodi did you place `application.yml` in `/test/resources`? That is important. Also, did you annotate the test class with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and @SpringBootTest` like in my example? If not, please update the question with those details by showing the whole test class

Comment: yes, the configuration is as you mentioned. One thing I am not sure of is, when I want to run the test file, I right click the file and chose `Run` is that right ? Because the exception seems to be raised because of `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` when creating some class in my project (I didn't load this class anywhere in my test class)

Comment: @stodi You'll need to add enough configuration to be able to get the application running. You can start by copying config from you production `application.yml` if you're comfortable with that - meaning anything you're sure will not cause changes in production

Comment: it's working now, I thought the application.yml will automatically load the main .yml file and then override properties from .yml test file but it seems it is not the casem I needed to add some fileStorageService properties to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A mock object is a dummy implementation for an interface or a class in which you define the output of certain method calls.

You need to define your rule, for example:

```
Mockito.when(userRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(user));
```

Comment: But like that I am not testing the function anymore. The function actually will not return all the users in the repository but it will execute a JPQL query using the EntityManager

Comment: If you want to test 'functionIwantToTest' this is ok in my opinion. You're not testing your UserRepository. For this another unit test is necessary.

Comment: I want to say that the function doesn't use the findAll() function, it was just an example. It actually perform a JPQL query with EntityManager